# React Native Dimensions iOS Change Event Doesn't Trigger

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a very simple event listener in my componentDidMount to listen for changes to the Dimensions, this never fires in my iOS simulator on iPhone (multiple models) but it does fire on the iPad Simulator and works fine in Android.

```
componentDidMount() {

    Dimensions.addEventListener( 'change', () =>
       {
         this.getOrientation();
       });

}
```

```js
getOrientation = () => {
  alert("Trigger Called"); // never fires in iPhone Simulator, but works on iPad Simulator and Android

  if (Dimensions.get("screen").width < Dimensions.get("screen").height) {
    this.setState({ screenOrientation: "portrait" });
  } else {
    this.setState({ screenOrientation: "landscape" });
  }
};
```

Am I doing something wrong? I also tried using EXPO Orientation but had the exact same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, it seems when using Overlay from react-native-elements it does not fire the change event. Removing it fixed it on the iPhone X(s)